# bad practice ? React and ES6 without Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was thinking that what if we bundle all the classes we have into a single file but don't use babel to polyfill it to ES5 .
and if the browser didn't support rs6 use babel in the browser or load the polly filled bundle and add the dependencies manually.
i don't know if it's a good idea to do that , but i think babel adds a huge size to my bundle . i have 300kb of code (not minified) with almost no dependencies (only react and router).but after bundling and minifing i get a huge file with 1mb of size.maybe im doing something wrong here.i also used preact instead of react , but it didn't help me that much.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Using babel increases filesize, but its not x3 ... Something is wrong with your bundling

Comment: you need to share your config files at least: babelrc/webpack.config/package.json

Comment: Of course you can do that. I doubt that you'll manually get your **total** payload down below the 1MB size. You can use a CDN of the react and router dependencies to reduce your bundle size.

Answer (score -1):

Babel shouldn't end up in your bundle. `babel-polyfill` might, if you need some features it provides, and it can be fairly large.

What toolchain are you using? If you use Webpack, you can analyze the bundle's size with e.g. [webpack-xray](https://akx.github.io/webpack-xray/) (disclaimer: my project).